# Convert u16string to float

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-16

I have a utf16 encoded string, I want to convert it to float

**For Example**
If have a utf16 string like `u"1342.223"` it should return `1342.223` in floats, if it was utf8 i used to convert it using `stod` function, but how to do this job on utf16 enocoded string `std::u16string`

Comment: I suppose you are seeking some standard way of accomplishing it, instead of writing the function yourself?

Comment: Convert to string and use `std::stof`.

Comment: @Ron But it can't be fast.

Comment: @Mohit how fast do you need? Did you measure to make sure that the conversion is the bottleneck?

Comment: It's not ideal but you could write a pretty fast conversion being that you only have `10` different characters to convert.

Comment: Use ICU library

Comment: If your system has `16bit` wide characters (like Windows) you could use `std::wistringstream in(L"1342.223"); in >> d;`. But that's not going to be particularly quick (or portable).

Comment: `std::stod()` and `std::stof()` accept `std::string` and `std::wstring` as input. If you have a `std::u16string`, you will have to convert it to one of those other string types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard function for this. If you can use `std::wstring` on a system that happens to use `16bit` wide characters, you could use:

```
double d;
std::wistringstream(L"1342.223") >> d;
```

Otherwise you could take advantage of the simple conversion of numeric digits from `UTF-16` to `ASCII/UTF-8` to write a fast conversion function. It is not ideal but should be reasonably efficient:

```
double u16stod(std::u16string const& u16s)
{
    char buf[std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 + 1];

    std::transform(std::begin(u16s), std::end(u16s), buf,
        [](char16_t c){ return char(c); });

    buf[u16s.size()] = '\0'; // terminator

    // some error checking here?
    return std::strtod(buf, NULL);
}
```

Comment: What about using `std::transform()` instead of `make_narrow()`? `char buf[max_digits10+1] = {}; std::transform(u16s.begin(), u16s.end(), buf, [](char16_t ch){ return char(ch); });`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's a great idea, thnx.

Answer (score 1):

First, conversion of an utf16 *numeric* character string to a narrow character string is trivial. Even if you cannot be sure that the narrow character set is ASCII for 7 bits characters, C guarantees that code '0' to '9' shall be consecutive, and it is also true for Unicode (0x30 to 0x39). So code can be as simple as (only depends on `<string>` inclusion:

```
double u16strtod(const std::u16string& u16) {
    char *beg = new char[u16.size() + 1];
    char *str = beg;
    for (char16_t uc: u16) {
        if (uc == u' ') *str++ = ' ';     // special processing for possible . and space
        else if (uc == u'.') *str++ = '.';
        else if ((uc < u'0') || (uc > u'9')) break;  // could use better error processing
        else {
            *str++ = '0' + (uc - u'0');
        }
    }
    *str++ = '\0';
    char *end;
    double d = strtod(beg, &end);   // could use better error processing
    delete[] beg;
    return d;
}
```

It is even simpler if narrow charset is ASCII:

```
double u16strtod(const std::u16string& u16) {
    char *beg = new char[u16.size() + 1];
    char *str = beg;
    for (char16_t uc: u16) {
        if ((uc <= 0) || (uc >= 127)) break;  // can only contain ASCII characters
        else {
            *str++ = uc;      // and the unicode code IS the ASCII code
        }
    }
    *str++ = '\0';
    char *end;
    double d = strtod(beg, &end);
    delete[] beg;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: I would use `std::string` instead of `new char[]`, and then use `std::stod()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that your string is nicely-formatted (e.g. no spaces), and *if and only if performance is critical* (i.e. if you're parsing millions or billions of numbers), don't dismiss the possibility of just decoding it yourself, looping over the string. Look for the standard library source code  (perhaps compare libc++ and libstdc++) to see what they do, and adapt it. Of course, in these cases, you should also take care to parallelize your work, try to exploit SIMD and so on.